# Why the body is drowning in the swamp?

Tags: density, fluid-statics, buoyancy

Is it correct explanation why does the body sink?

Swamp is not a liquid, but particle suspension, that's why Archimedes principle not working and upward buoyant force not applied to the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey here is a text about quicksand, which I assume is a similar problem : 
http://journals.fcla.edu/cee/article/viewFile/84539/81576

They take the mean density to apply Archimede principle.

Their conclusion is that one is unlikely to sink totaly in the quicksand !

In swamps, I assume that the mean density makes that one can actually sink.

So the answer would be that Archimede principle does apply, but you have to take into account the mean density, and also the viscosity of the swamp that makes the sinking slower.